# Angular 4 build --prod bundle has an error

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an issue after building my Angular 4 application. In the vendor file i have an error on this line:

The IDE I use is VSCode and has a hint saying to the 't' in 'function t':
"[js] this constructor function may be converted to a class declaration"

I tried to use ng build with build-optimizer=false too, updated the angular-cli, and tried a lot of things, but still nothing.

```js
function t(t, e, n) {
  this.routeReuseStrategy = t, this.futureState = e, this.currState = n
}
```

my package.json looks like this:

```js
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve -port 8002 --proxy-config proxy.conf.js",
    "build": "ng build --aot false --prod && node bundled.conf.js --build-optimizer false"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "2.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/common": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/core": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/forms": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/http": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.4.4",
    "@angular/router": "4.4.4",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta",
    "core-js": "2.5.1",
    "date-fns": "2.0.0-alpha.6",
    "ie-shim": "0.1.0",
    "node-sass": "4.8.3",
    "rxjs": "5.4.3",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.4.4",
    "@types/bootstrap": "3.3.36",
    "@types/node": "8.0.31",
    "concat-files": "0.1.1",
    "glob": "7.1.2",
    "foreach": "2.0.5",
    "https-proxy-agent": "2.1.0",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  },
```

Comment: Could you give the code around this function ?

Comment: Actually I am not sure, which code causes this. This ends up in my vendor bundle. I found this kind of code in animations, platform-browser, and router as well.

Comment: Did you try removing and downloading again the node modules folder ?

Comment: Yes I did it a few times. Also tried this whole process with different node versions.

Comment: And by updatign the versions of your dependencies ? It doesn't look like a big project, you can surely try

Comment: I tried that too. I updated them to 4.4.7 which is the last in angular 4. Getting the same error

Comment: And going to version 5 ? or 4.5 ?

Comment: In case of updating to angular 5 I would have to do a lot of code rewrite. So in this case that would be the last solution. Also we don't know that this would solve it

Comment: That's why I was asking you to try, and not telling you it is the solution. If you can't no problem, I understand. After all, it's just a hint, you can ignore it, but how can you have a vendor issue in your IDE ? Are you watching the dist folder ?

Comment: I tried to have a third party library running which worked fine locally, but not after the build in production mode and it looks like this is the root problem of that.

Comment: Then simply remove your dist folder and the hint should go away !